# How can I prevent Control+Alt+D from logging me out (of Gnome 2.22 on Debian 5)?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, shutdown

I was using Emacs, and typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in order to run Emacs' "down-list" command.  I was dismayed to see, however, that I was instantly logged out; I assume this is some Gnome keyboard shortcut.

I looked under System/Preferences/Keyboard shortcuts, and saw nothing pertinent; I then ran `gconf-editor` and searched through it for , and still saw nothing pertinent.

So ... how do I disable this "feature"?

Comment: May be it's that all your windows were minimized (hidden?)  That appears to be 'show desktop' shotcut, not 'log me out'.  You might try pressing the same combination again to get your windows back.

Comment: er, pressing the same combination again does nothing, because at that point I'm looking at the "please log in" screen.  In any case, I've mapped "show desktop" to M-d (i.e., I hold the Windows key down and then press d), and it works fine.

Comment: Maybe that's a shortcut to switch user then?

Comment: Ctrl+D is the end-of-file character in most Unix-land.   Typically shells will respond to this by exiting.  So if your Ctrl+Alt+D gets mapped to Ctrl+D along the line, having the shell exit would be explainable.  In Bash, you can disable this by setting the IGNOREEOF built-in variable.

Comment: @Stabledog: I'm familiar with the behavior of Ctrl+D in shells; this is different.